# combine stripping white space and html tags

Tags: python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I'm looking for the possibility to strip html tags and white space from the parsed text using Beautiful Soup. The problem is that I can't combine these two.

Here is the whole script:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from urllib2 import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

word = "Drop"
url = ('http://civil.ge/eng/category.php?id=10')
soup = bs(urlopen(url).read())
titz = soup.find("div", {"class": "archtype_category_block"})

for t in titz.find_all('div', {'class': 'archive_type_article_title'}):
    if word in t.encode('utf-8').strip():
        print t.prettify()
```

The result with `prettify()` is:

```
<div class="archive_type_article_title">
 Prosecutors Drop Objection to Release of Ex-MoD Officials from Pretrial     Detention
</div>
```

and with `get_text()` I get clean text with lots of white space before and after it. Any solutions to this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I used Python 3 and wasn't able to reproduce your spacing problem.  So maybe that is an answer!

I would change `print t.prettify()` to `print t.prettify().join(mystring.split())` and see if that fixes your problem.

Also, your code will only get the first `archtype_category_block`, maybe that is what you want, but if you want all of them you have to change `titz = soup.find("div", {"class": "archtype_category_block"})` to `for titz in soup.find_all("div", {"class": "archtype_category_block"}):`

Comment: Thanks for answering.  `join()` produces `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable`.